# std::string ::toupper on the input string

Tags: c++, std, toupper

Can I perform a `::toupper` transformation on the same string that is the input?

i.e.:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
```

or do I need a different target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's legal, and perfectly idiomatic. It's a very common way to do it.

Comment: As it happens, this is precisely the example given for `std::transform` on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform